# Spring Boot WebClient- How to pass parameter in webclient Get call and how to get Page Object in return type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8

`I need to call an API through webclient.[Spring Boot]

Example Rest controller API looks like ---

`

```
@Getmapping("/demo")


public page<Object> find(Pageable pageable)
{
     return repository.findall(pageable);
}
```

Web client call issues I'm Facing. how to pass Pageable object argument in webclient and how to get the page return type object in webclient calling method.

Code i tried :

`webClient.get() .uri("/demo") .bodytomono(Page.class) .block();`

But the above block throwing exception., My issue is like  how to pass pageable object argument through webclient and how to get the return type of page object in webclient.

I'm new to webclient can anyone please help on my issue.`

Comment: Don't call block in a reactive stack. You don't pass the pageable object you pass request parameters like page, size etc.

Comment: Thanks Deinum for your reply.Can you give small example of what you said it would be really helpful for me to understand this

Comment: For passing request parameters you may construct the URI string with request params (`/demo?start=0&max=10`) or use a `UriBuilder` instead: `webClieng.get().uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/demo").queryParam("start", 0).queryparam("max", 10).build())....`

Comment: Thanks  Farhan Nasim, it really solved my issue